# Is there a method in Ruby Object to pass itself to a block or proc?

Tags: ruby, methods

I think it would be natural to have in Ruby something like:

```
class Object
  def yield_self
    yield(self)
  end
end
```

Does there exist a method like this by any chance?  (I haven't found.)  Does anybody else think it would be nice to have it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848967/is-there-a-pipe-equivalent-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield_self` has been added to ruby core a month ago as of June 2017. https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/58528

It's in ruby 2.5.0 after revision number 58528, although I'm not exactly sure how to get that code yet. Perhaps if someone knows how they can edit this answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want the complexity of:

```
Object.new.yield_self do |foo|
  ...
end
```

When the following is almost exactly equivalent:

```
foo = Object.new
...
```

Comment: To chain method calls.  It looks like a missing option to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed the `tap` method that does almost exactly what you're asking:

```
x = [].tap do |array|
  array << 'foo'
  array << 9
end
p x

#=> ["foo", 9]
```

As Rob Davis points out, there's a subtle but important difference between `tap` and your method. The return value of `tap` is the receiver (i.e., the anonymous array in my example), while the return value of your method is the return value of the block.

You can see this in [the source for the `tap` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
VALUE
rb_obj_tap(VALUE obj)
{
    rb_yield(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

We're returning the `obj` that was passed into the function rather than the return value of `rb_yield(obj)`. If this distinction is crucial, then `tap` is not what you need. Otherwise, it seems like a good fit.

Comment: No, `tap` returns the receiver, which is its primary benefit. In the original question, `yield_self` returns the result of the `yield`, instead. This difference doesn't show up in your example because both `tap` and the block return the array.

Comment: Thanks, i know about the tap, but a method like `yield_self` looks so natural to me, that i want to make a feature request for it.  It could be used in method chains.  It also seems to be along the lines of a recently discussed request for a method that would return `self`: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373